# Multiple Inheritance in Java using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with multiple inheritance since (obviously) `class A extends B, C { }` is not possible in Java. The traditional workaround is using B and C as interfaces. But as you know JPA doesn't support interface-entities. A workaround would be to use an aggregation instead of a composition but I want to make sure that `A` cannot exist without `B`. Therefore I need a composition. I show my problem in an example

| family_name | kindergarden_name | child_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| is not null | can be null (not dependent to col3) | can be null (not dependent to col2) |

I create a few classes:

```
class Family
 - name: String
```

```
class Child
 - name: String
```

```
class Kindergarden
 - name: String
```

```
class FamilyWithChild extends Family, Child
```

```
class FamilyWithKindergarden extends Family, Kindergarden
```

```
class FamilyWithChildAndKindergarden extends FamilyWithChild, Kindergarden
 - child: Child
```

How would you solve this problem. I haven't found any real solutions besides making a aggregation.

The table shown above might have more columns with additional information about Family, Child and Kindergarden.

Making an aggregation would work but this is not a good option for me in that scenario.

**EDIT: I made an other example because the previous one was kinda misleading!**

I want to make an other example since the previous one was kinda misleading. The usecase of a composition is if `A` requires `B` in order to exist (`A extends B` in Java). An aggregation does not require `B` (`class B {private A a;}` in Java). My example was very misleading so lets use an other one that is very different.

I want to implement employees that might have multiple "types". This is the data structure in sql:
emp_id | name | given_name | working_since | volunteer_grp
------ | ---- | ---------- | ----------------- | ---------
1 | Name 1 | GivenName 1 | 2001-12-30 11:12:13 | null
2 | Name 2 | GivenName 2 | null | GrpA
3 | Name 3 | GivenName 3 | 2001-12-30 14:15:16 | GrpB
4 | Name 4 | GivenName 4 | null | GrpA
5 | Name 5 | GivenName 5 | 2001-12-30 17:18:19  | null

Now lets implement this:

```
class Employee:
 - id: int
 # name: String
 # givenName: String
 # workingSince: Date
 # volunteerGroup: String
 + isCurrentlyWorking(): boolean
 + isVolunteer(): boolean
 + isWorkingVolunteer(): boolean
```

And use it as follows:

```
public class EmployeeImpl extends Employee {
  private List<EmployeeType> getType() {
    final var list = new ArrayList<EmployeeType>();
    if (this.isCurrentlyWorking()) {
      list.add(EmployeeType.WORKING);
    }
    if (this.isVolunteer()) {
      list.add(EmployeeType.VOLUNTEER);
    }
    return list;
  }

  public boolean hasType(EmployeeType type) {
    return getType().contains(type);
  }
}
```

This would be the easiest way to check what type it is (i.e. if volunteer should have less permissions in a programm). If I want to do certain things based on the type of employee it quite tricky. Lets add `+ connect(): void` to employee and the functionality of this method should be different based on the type of the employee - therefore either we do:

```
public void connect() {
  establishConnection();
  if (!hasType(EmployeeType.WORKING)) {
    super.currentlyWorking = new Date();
  }

  if (!hasType(EmployeeType.VOLUNTEER)) {
    showSalaryPanel();
    return;
  }
  showTutorialPanel();
}
```

Yes this is quite simple but this can get more complicated. Therefore if there are different types of the base class instead of chain if-statements its recommended to use a composition and `instanceof` instead of `getType().equals(XType.YYY)`. Additional benefits are that each type can have its own fuctionality of `connect()` without using a chain of if-elseif-statements:

```
class Employee:
 - id: int
 # name: String
 # givenName: String

class WorkingEmployee extends Employee:
 - since: Date

class Volunteer extends Employee:
 - group: String

class WorkingVolunteer extends Volunteer, WorkingEmployee:
```

But this is not possible in Java. Now: Lets imagine for a moment that `employee` also has a attribute `- company_party: boolean`. Now it gets completely out of hand. What is a good solution for this?

Comment: Maybe you can do an optional relation (composition) which is Nullable and simulate inheritance using it? In RDB world it would be 1 ... 0-1 relation I guess. So it means that you have an entity which can (but doesn't have to) point to another entity (table). Will it work for you?

Comment: This was an option I was thinking about as well. I’m just curious if someone has a better solution.

Comment: Aggregation is correct -- a Family has 0..N Children, a Kindergarten has 0..N Children. A Child has 1 family and 1 Kindergarten. With your model each Kindergarten has a single child, each family has a single child.

Comment: @Lara According the code and semantics of naming you provided, I don't see any urge of inheritance. Looks like a common relation between kindergarden-family and child-family and etc. Then you should use relational mappings. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Reason being that `if (obj.getChild() != null)` is a bad design pattern and you should rather use `if (obj instanceof Child)`

Comment: If there is an optional relation you can either use `!= null` or `Optional` class with `ofNullable` method. Sometimes you have to compare to `null`. Alternative is null object pattern https://www.baeldung.com/java-null-object-pattern .

Comment: My presumption is each of these need to be an object ,BUT , with implemented methods?  And constructed globals? Which is more important implemented method code or global variables?

Comment: I don't know how abstract classes would really get along with DAOs and DTOs but with an outside capsule class as some sort of handler you could perform something like aggregation by casting an initial data referencing holder class to any abstract classes made for purpose.

Comment: If you have an optional relationship, then `if (obj.getChild() != null)` is not bad design -- although depending on what you are doing `for (Child c: obj.getChildren())` is more natural. Using inheritance for HAS-A relationships like the ones in your question is not the right approach.

Comment: You need to explain your scenario in more detail to tell us why aggregation is not a good option.

Comment: And what is your definition of aggregation vs composition?